# Request web services that use self-signed certificate

Tags: c#, azure, ubuntu, ssl

I try to connect to a elasticsearch ubuntu server(on Azure) that use a self-signed certificate. But when i try to connect with NEST i get a message telling me that the certificate is not vaild.

When i add this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

in my Global.asax i get after a long timeout a 503 message.

Do I need to import the certificate somewhere (Azure)? Now I have only generated it on the server.
What should I do to make it work?

UPDATE:

```
        var ConSettings = new ConnectionSettings("https://....");
        ConSettings.SetBasicAuthentication("USERNAME", "PASS");

        var _client = new ElasticClient(ConSettings);
        var Data = _client.IndexExists("Users");  <-- throws error, "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."
```

Comment: Global.asax sounds like asp.mvc. So you have some client, an asp mvc site and an ubuntu server. The client connects to asp mvc, and asp mvc connects to elastsic search? Which one does return the 503? Is this machine under your control? Because 503 means "service not available" and that is a return code that somehow has to be set manually so you have to fix it on the machine where it is emitted.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. I Have a asp.net mvc site thats connect to elasticsearch on a vm on azure. There was no problem with http but when i try to connect with https i get a message that the cert is invalid. I can connect to the ubuntu server with ssh. I can connect with my browser to elasticsearch, but when i connect i get a warning about a invalid cert. ("untrusted certificates")

Comment: Which server is throwing 503? Ubuntu or ASP? What is "NEST"?  You should show some code, for instance how you try to connect from asp to elasticsearch.

Comment: Can you connect to your ASP site through https? Maybe the 503 is coming from there because https is not enabled? Where is your ASP site located?

Comment: When i go to the url in the browser that i try to connect to from my asp.net mvc app i get, "untrusted certificates" And when i try to connect to the server from my asp.net website i get, "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

Comment: Seems like the `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;` is not woking. I never personally used it, but other answers suggest it shoud be `=> {return true;};` instead of just `=> true;`

Comment: I think i must download the cert from the ubuntu machine and install it on the machine i run the asp.net website. But i don't know how i can get the cert file from the vm and how i can install it.

Comment: You can download https certificate by opening base ElasticSearch url in chrome. (You need to have network access to the box): [Check Chrome's connection to a site](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617?hl=en). However, you can install the certificate on VM in Azure not in PaaS service. So, you will have to deploy your application on full blown VM. However, I do not see real value to use self-signed certificate. You can easily get trusted certificate for free, for example, here [sslstart](https://www.startssl.com/).

Comment: I have a Azure website and the VM with elasticsearch. I use https://xxxxx.cloudapp.net/ for the connection with the vm. Is there any cert for cloudapp.net that i can use? I dont think i can create a own on sslstart for that domain?